# Any drawback about using layaureo with memoir?

Tags: memoir, geometry

I usually use latex to write small-ish reports/articles and the standard classes always did me right.

Given I'm using A4 paper I always found `layaureo` to do a pretty good job of *filling the page* without breaking typography rules too much.

Now I need to write a longer work and I'm looking at the `memoir` class.

Given this class seems to follow a much more do-it-all philosophy than the standard classes, is there any downside about using `layaureo` with it? or should I try to emulate layaureo geometry within `memoir` itself?

Comment: Since `memoir` is compatible with geometry, and `layaureo` is simply a wrapper for `geometry` I don't see any problems using it with `memoir`.

Comment: Memoir is compatible, but you will lose the typographical aesthetic benefits of Memoir's layout mechanisms. While you can use Memoir and then stomp all over it, part of the point of choosing Memoir is a desire to layout your pages according to one of various typographical principles. It is not the only reason, but it is a major part of the class's appeal. Hence, you should get clear about why you do want to use Memoir, if you want something different.

Comment: Personally, I'd see if you can use Memoir's configuration macros first. Load more code only if you really must. Loading more stuff always increases the chances of mysterious inconsistencies and territorial conflicts, if not with Memoir, then with other things. Plus, the various facilities of Memoir are designed to work together and will work best when used together. That is, life is likely to be more straightforward if you don't do stuff memoir wants to do in conflicting ways.

Comment: @cfr I'm all for embracing the typographical principles `memoir` is based on. The whole point of using it was to only think about the content and let it do its thing about layout. Do you know if are there recommended margin settings to use it with a4 paper? single column with binding and no margin notes.

Comment: @filippo Just follow the guide in Memoir's manual. It shows you how to layout the page in various ways and includes recommendations. It also tells you what it will do or can do automatically, so you can specify one or two key parameters and let Memoir sort it out.

Comment: If your longer work is more like a novel than a math thesis or a newspaper article, also have a look at the `novel` document class. But do not use `layaureo` because `novel` has built-in layout settings that do not use `geometry`.

Comment: thanks, it's a scientific thesis though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Warning; I'm the original author of `memoir`). Try `layaureo` with `memoir` and see if it works. However in general I think it would be better to use `memoir's` native facilities to set up your desired layout. Note that `memoir` does provide several layouts corresponding to some traditional forms via, for example, `\medievalpage`, `\isopage` and `\semiisopage`. Read Chapter 2 of the documentation `> texdoc memoir`.

In one of your comments you basically asked if there were recommended layouts. My *A Few Notes on Book Design* `(>texdoc memdesign)` lists the details of some 32 page designs that are considered to be "good" throughout the ages, all of which can be configured within `memoir`. I'm sorry to say that filling an A4 page with text would not be among these.

Comment: Thank you, I tried `layaureo`. But it feels wrong using it with your beautiful class. At the moment I'm using `\isopage[10]` with `0.8cm` binding. I get about the same line width as layaureo, but I'm finding the page way too full for my liking, will probably increase margins. Will look into `memdesign`, sounds like an interesting read. About A4, it's unfortunate how it became the defacto standard for european documents. It roughly works with double column layouts or wide margin notes but it's way too big for single column.